# SQLite Operational Error in text column

Tags: string, text, sqlite

I am getting

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "[24:-2]": syntax error
```

when inserting values into a table. I am using Python and [24:-2] is to trim a very long string. The string is around 12.000 characters long and the table column is defined as TEXT.

Can you enlighten me why I am getting the error?

Comment: Error is self describing . you are not using proper syntax to write the SQL query. What is the query ?

Comment: Hmm, self describing? Syntax is as follows:

    CUR.execute("INSERT INTO de VALUES(m_id, start, s_zip, s_lat, s_lon, dest, d_lat, d_lon, dist, tid, j_str[24:-2])")

Comment: try using this :  CUR.execute("INSERT INTO de VALUES(m_id, start, s_zip, s_lat, s_lon, dest, d_lat, d_lon, dist, tid, " j_str[24:-2 ]")")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python and SQL are two different languages.

To get Python values into SQL, use [parameters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html):

```py
CUR.execute("INSERT INTO de VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            (m_id, start, s_zip, s_lat, s_lon, dest, d_lat, d_lon, dist, tid, j_str[24:-2]))
```